# SPARQL Parser for INSERT and DELETE queries

Tags: python, parsing, sparql, rdf

I need to test if a certain `SPARQL` queries are indeed an `INSERT` or `DELETE` statements. Therefore, I have been using different parsers (mainly, `fyzz` and `SPARQLWrapper`) as follow:

```
try:
    sparql = parse(Query_String)
except Exception as e:
    raise ContentsUnacceptable(
        " The query attribute does not conform to the SPARQL query syntax !!")
```

and :

```
try:
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper("local/graph/file")
    sparql.setQuery(Query_String)
    results = sparql.query().convert()
except Exception as e:
    raise ContentsUnacceptable(
        " The query does not conform to the SPARQL query syntax !!")
```

Both of my code work fine with `SELECT` statements, but as soon as I try an `INSERT` or `DELETE` statements, I got the exception written on my code `"The query does not conform to the SPARQL query syntax !!"` which it may means that the INSERT and DELETE statement are not recognizable by the parser. According to my research there are mainly those two parser for SPARQL queries. is there a way to make those statements recognizable by the fyzz and SPARQLWrapper parser?

Comment: Are you trying to execute `INSERT` or `DELETE` on the read-only DBpedia SPARQL endpoint? You shouldn't get *syntax* errors, but you will indeed get exceptions...

Comment: @TJC Why do you think that everybody can change the data of a public endpoint?

Comment: Yes i figured it out as well that the link I provided is public and i changed that to a local directory. Still didn't work. ( I only need to check the syntax of the queries not to execute them)

Comment: @TJR - "It didn't work" and "got an exception" tells us nothing. What exception? How did it not work? and what exactly was "it" that got that exception / didn't work?

Comment: @TallTed As i explained in my questions. After trying out both of the parser. I got the exception montionned on my code " " The query does not conform to the SPARQL query syntax !!"" that s exactly what i got. But when changing the INSERT by a SELECT statement, it continue the work and no exception was displayed which mean that the parsers may not support INSERT statement. therefore I want to know if there are another parsers you may know or maybe some other ways to change my code to make the INSERT statement recognizable.

Comment: The code for SPARQLWrapper you are using tries to _execute a query_, rather than just parsing it, which is what causes the error. Rather than asking about other libraries (which is considered offtopic on StackOverflow), you should be focusing on how you can fix your code. I'm no RDFLib/SPARQLWrapper expert but I think [the documentation about prepared queries](http://rdflib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro_to_sparql.html#prepared-queries) might be a good starting point.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra everything you said in your comment I already know. thx for trying anyway. But one question: who decides which questions are in and offtopic in stackoverflow ? because I dont believe what you said is true(Plenty of similar question on the platform already!!). If you are sure about your statement plz provide what prove that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JeenBroekstra this only one example from many others: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984965/parsing-sparql-queries). And I dont see any downvoted on this question for example.

Comment: @TJR look, I pointed out to you that tool recommendation questions are considered offtopic here, and even showed you the help section where that is explicitly mentioned. Examples of questions that haven't (yet) been downvoted or closed are irrelevant. I'm not here to police your behavior, I'm just suggesting that following the house rules will improve your chances of getting an answer to your question. You can continue to act indignant about this, or you can just fix it, get a good answer and actually solve your problem. Your choice.

Comment: Just saw you edited your question to reformulate things, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SPARQLWrapper is not actually intended as a SPARQL parser. All it does is act as a client for a SPARQL endpoint service - AFAICT the actual parsing of the query string is done by the endpoint itself.

In your specific example, you're pointing SPARQLWrapper to a local file, which simply won't work, because a local file is not a SPARQL endpoint. In the attempt where you *are* pointing to a SPARQL endpoint, that endpoint is not accepting SPARQL updates (because, understandably, they don't allow remote clients to update their data).

If you wish to stick with SPARQLWrapper, a (*very* clunky) solution would be to set up your own SPARQL endpoint service, configure it to allow remote updates, and then use that endpoint to validate your queries/updates (there's plenty of free SPARQL endpoint implementations available including RDF4J Server and Jena Fuseki, to name but two popular ones).

But as said, this is a clunky solution: if your goal is simply to parse the string to validate its syntax, you should use an actual SPARQL parser in Python. [RDFLib's SPARQL Parser](http://rdflib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidocs/rdflib.plugins.sparql.html#module-rdflib.plugins.sparql.parser) is probably a good choice here. I'm no Python expert but I imagine something along these lines:

```
import rdflib.plugins.sparql.parser

parser.parseQuery("SELECT ...")
```

and

```
parser.parseUpdate("INSERT ...")
```

can help you out.