# Parsing SPARQL UPDATE queries with rdflib

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I am trying to programmatically analyze a SPARQL 1.1 UPDATE query using rdflib.

Using the following (Python 3.5) code:

```
from rdflib.plugins.sparql.parser import parseUpdate
from pprint import pprint

qs = '''DELETE {
  <> a <urn:type:A> , <urn:type:b> ;
    <urn:p:a> ?x .
} INSERT {
  <> <urn:p:a> "hello" .
} WHERE {
  <> <urn:p.a> ?x .
}'''

q = parseUpdate(qs)
pprint(q)
```

I get the following result:

```
{'prologue': [([], {})],
 'request': [{'delete': {'quads': {'triples': [([rdflib.term.URIRef(''), rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type'), rdflib.term.URIRef('urn:type:B'), rdflib.term.URIRef(''), rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type'), rdflib.term.URIRef('urn:type:C'), rdflib.term.URIRef(''), rdflib.term.URIRef('urn:p:b'), rdflib.term.Variable('x')], {})]}},
              'insert': {'quads': {'triples': [([rdflib.term.URIRef(''), rdflib.term.URIRef('urn:p:b'), literal_{'string': rdflib.term.Literal('hello')}], {})]}},
              'where': {'part': [{'triples': [([rdflib.term.URIRef(''), PathAlternative_{'part': [PathSequence_{'part': [PathElt_{'part': rdflib.term.URIRef('urn:p:b')}]}]}, rdflib.term.Variable('x')], {})]}]}}]}
```

This *sort of* makes sense but it is very clunky. The most incomprehensible part of it is that all terms for each statement are smushed into one list instead of being divided by triples.

I looked at the (quite lacking) documentation of RDFlib and even into the source code responsible for this parsing looking for some convenience methods to extract the triples per statement, to no avail.

Looking for alternative and better documented methods to do this, I read [Parsing SPARQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984965/parsing-sparql-queries) and looked at alternative libraries but they all seem to be alpha or dead.

Does anybody have any pointers to understand the above data structure?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that anybody here can tell you something about the design decisions of the RDFLib SPARQL parser. If somebody is able to answer your question, then the developers: *"Support is available through the rdflib-dev group:

https://groups.google.com/group/rdflib-dev*"

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will post the question there if I don't find an answer.